# C++ algorithm to advance iterator while condition is true

Tags: c++, algorithm

Having a pair of iterators `[begin, end)` I want to advance `begin` while a condition is true and I didn't reach `end`. As I don't know any "direct" algorithm from the standard library to do this I'm using:

```
std::find_if_not(begin, end, condition);
```

but my problem is that the name of the function does't express my intention to advance `begin` while the condition is true in a clear way.

Is any algorithm in the C++ standard library to advance an iterator while a condition is true?

Comment: why do you need an STL algorithm? Try `while(condition) {++iter;}`

Comment: `std::find_if_not` advances the first iterator while the condition is true (until it is false), stopping at the second iterator.  This exactly matches what you are asking?  I mean, **exactly**?  You just don't like the name?

Comment: So something that does what `find_if_not` does but with a different name? `auto advance_while_true = [](auto begin, auto end, auto cond) { return std::find_if_not(begin, end, cond); };`

Comment: @davidhigh Your `condition` is going to have to include "don't advance past the end", or it will be a bit of crash prone code.

Comment: `#define advance_until_true std::find_if_not`

Comment: I'm sensing, the OP wants to templatize on the used condition shorten his source code for multiple execution of similar find_if_not executions

Comment: @davidhigh because what you wrote is wrong, you don't check for begin != end:)

Comment: @Yakk something like that. It would be more clear something like advance_if other similar name...

Comment: @Felics: right, correct it yourself :). As an alternative you could also use `std::advance(iter, condition)` which advances the iterator if condition is true, otherwise does nothing (... implicit conversion of `bool` to `int` is working here).

Comment: You will never make C++ look like natural English. Programmers learn to read computer-speak instead. To me, `begin = std::find_if_not(begin, end, condition)` says exactly what you want it to say, just not in natural English. But it **is** in a common language that all **STL** users speak.

Comment: @davidhigh std::advance does something completely different. In the best case scenario can be used to advance only 0 or 1 positions:)

Comment: @Galik Yes, you are right:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is most easily expressed by the idiom...

```
while (condition (begin++));
```

And if you want to check against an end iterator, just add that to the conditions...

```
while (begin != end && condition(begin++));
```

It's a nice little trick (that goes back to C) because it works for things that aren't even technically iterators like...

```
// Consume leading whitespace
while (isspace(ch = getchar()));
```

Comment: I like 'while (begin != end && condition(begin++));' because expresses better the intention than 'find_if_not' and it's also shorter:)

Answer (score 2):

C++14:

```
template<class...Args>
auto advance_while_true( Args&&... args ) {
  return std::find_if_not( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
}
```

but really, just use `find_if_not`.  The name might not match your description of the problem, but as a `std` library algorithm, it is relatively famous.

If the condition is common, write a wrapper that takes two (templetized) iterators and includes the condition inside itself.

```
template<class Iterator>
std::decay_t<Iterator> advance_while_foo( Iterator first, Iterator last ) {
  return std::find_if_not( std::forward<Iterator>(first), std::forward<Iterator>(last),
    [](auto&& x) {
      return foo(x);
    }
  );
}
```

which both uses the `std` algorithm for the guts (meaning it will be better written than if you write it yourself probably), and gives it a name (`foo`) that in theory should be appropriate.

(`forward` and `decay_t` is probably overkill.  Replace `auto&&` with the stored type `const&` and `std::decay_t<?>` with `typename std::decay<?>::type` if you aren't C++14.)

Comment: I don't see the point of `forward` when you are not taking the arguments by forwarding reference.

Comment: @t.c. Some git calling `advance_while_foo<myIterator&>`...  I should just `std::move` the `iterator`s in in practice.  Added `decay_t` to make the return value a value, not a reference, in case someone does the rude `&` thing.  Like I said, is probably overkill.